# Numerically order x-tick labels that are part letters, part number, in ggplot (rather than in alphabetical order)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below is my sample data for this question:

```
> sum_tab_cond_Loc
    condition loc_coord loc_id n_samples sum_dark         mean median          sd         sem
 1:    WT_CTL        a1      1        89    14816 166.47191011      0 381.5107853 40.44006236
 2:     MUT10        a2      2        89     5748  64.58426966      0 156.9145547 16.63290953
 3:      MUT9        a3      3        89        0   0.00000000      0   0.0000000  0.00000000
 4:      MUT8        a4      4        89        0   0.00000000      0   0.0000000  0.00000000
 5:      MUT7        a5      5        89     1065  11.96629213      0 112.8897742 11.96629213
 6:      MUT6        a6      6        89        2   0.02247191      0   0.2119996  0.02247191
 7:      MUT5        a7      7        89    23891 268.43820225     85 409.9059469 43.44994348
 8:      MUT4        a8      8        89     4691  52.70786517      0 197.9350331 20.98107155
 9:      MUT3        a9      9        89    17244 193.75280899     37 330.9582259 35.08150178
10:      MUT2       a10     10        89    19653 220.82022472     84 294.4198286 31.20843942
11:      MUT1       a11     11        89    32244 362.29213483    187 390.1419090 41.35495964
12:   MUT_CTL       a12     12        89    20547 230.86516854    144 284.6004053 30.16758263
13:    WT_CTL        b1     13        89        9   0.10112360      0   0.6224027  0.06597455
14:     MUT10        b2     14        89      934  10.49438202      0  59.0065720  6.25468412
15:      MUT9        b3     15        89     2591  29.11235955      0 184.8712966 19.59631825
16:      MUT8        b4     16        89        5   0.05617978      0   0.5299989  0.05617978
17:      MUT7        b5     17        89     3146  35.34831461      0  95.4808526 10.12095013
18:      MUT6        b6     18        89        0   0.00000000      0   0.0000000  0.00000000
19:      MUT5        b7     19        89    12080 135.73033708      0 379.4003571 40.21635742
20:      MUT4        b8     20        89      855   9.60674157      0  78.7162075  8.34390130
21:      MUT3        b9     21        89    27055 303.98876404    140 412.2091949 43.69408727
22:      MUT2       b10     22        89    29327 329.51685393    225 348.2187176 36.91111024
23:      MUT1       b11     23        89    31765 356.91011236    186 416.8646674 44.18756637
24:   MUT_CTL       b12     24        89    22682 254.85393258    161 318.7144116 33.78366006
25:    WT_CTL        c1     25        89    16498 185.37078652    117 245.1523822 25.98610054
26:     MUT10        c2     26        89     1169  13.13483146      0  91.5546522  9.70477372
27:      MUT9        c3     27        89     6932  77.88764045      0 247.3136782 26.21519746
28:      MUT8        c4     28        89      228   2.56179775      0  23.6359487  2.50540555
29:      MUT7        c5     29        89      624   7.01123596      0  43.9693836  4.66074534
30:      MUT6        c6     30        89     5643  63.40449438      0 277.5699224 29.42235293
31:      MUT5        c7     31        89    19713 221.49438202     93 320.8856750 34.01381353
32:      MUT4        c8     32        89       26   0.29213483      0   1.4632020  0.15509910
33:      MUT3        c9     33        89    13328 149.75280899     21 290.6393141 30.80770568
34:      MUT2       c10     34        89    16007 179.85393258     73 248.5571797 26.34700836
35:      MUT1       c11     35        89    19859 223.13483146     94 315.2131382 33.41252583
36:   MUT_CTL       c12     36        89    38148 428.62921348    316 417.0589500 44.20816028
37:    WT_CTL        d1     37        89      692   7.77528090      0  61.8612364  6.55727794
38:     MUT10        d2     38        89     5397  60.64044944      0 268.0002649 28.40797126
39:      MUT9        d3     39        89       16   0.17977528      0   0.8469437  0.08977585
40:      MUT8        d4     40        89        0   0.00000000      0   0.0000000  0.00000000
41:      MUT7        d5     41        89     1958  22.00000000      0 129.0508180 13.67935935
42:      MUT6        d6     42        89    13699 153.92134831      0 318.4321758 33.75374312
43:      MUT5        d7     43        89     3734  41.95505618      0 119.0242441 12.61654464
44:      MUT4        d8     44        89       19   0.21348315      0   1.7219961  0.18253123
45:      MUT3        d9     45        89    19630 220.56179775     49 322.1956265 34.15266810
46:      MUT2       d10     46        89    26129 293.58426966    156 349.9139767 37.09080735
47:      MUT1       d11     47        89    46637 524.01123596    412 571.9543945 60.62704457
48:   MUT_CTL       d12     48        89    36407 409.06741573    235 469.2885524 49.74448706
49:    WT_CTL        e1     49        89    14722 165.41573034      0 295.4558423 31.31825665
50:     MUT10        e2     50        89     4546  51.07865169      0 231.8792899 24.57915558
51:      MUT9        e3     51        89      542   6.08988764      0  57.2378690  6.06720198
52:      MUT8        e4     52        89       11   0.12359551      0   1.1659977  0.12359551
53:      MUT7        e5     53        89      210   2.35955056      0  22.0465660  2.33693132
54:      MUT6        e6     54        89     8996 101.07865169      0 307.3379922 32.57776202
55:      MUT5        e7     55        89    17278 194.13483146      0 500.1860834 53.01961880
56:      MUT4        e8     56        89     1724  19.37078652      0 113.0606617 11.98440617
57:      MUT3        e9     57        89    11738 131.88764045     20 223.2198487 23.66125664
58:      MUT2       e10     58        89    27963 314.19101124    146 406.5002202 43.08893716
59:      MUT1       e11     59        89    32120 360.89887640    209 417.5670345 44.26201713
60:   MUT_CTL       e12     60        89    23596 265.12359551    127 358.5456678 38.00576478
61:    WT_CTL        f1     61        89    12156 136.58426966      0 322.6320663 34.19893063
62:     MUT10        f2     62        89    10804 121.39325843      0 247.2559227 26.20907539
63:      MUT9        f3     63        89       11   0.12359551      0   0.7510633  0.07961255
64:      MUT8        f4     64        89      307   3.44943820      0  32.3282213  3.42678460
65:      MUT7        f5     65        89       31   0.34831461      0   2.8005727  0.29686011
66:      MUT6        f6     66        89     5828  65.48314607      0 117.8844882 12.49573076
67:      MUT5        f7     67        89     8880  99.77528090      0 299.0273913 31.69684008
68:      MUT4        f8     68        89      227   2.55056180      0  23.6354949  2.50535745
69:      MUT3        f9     69        89    19924 223.86516854    128 323.9902563 34.34289848
70:      MUT2       f10     70        89    30185 339.15730337    269 391.6490167 41.51471274
71:      MUT1       f11     71        89    23295 261.74157303    182 327.0673939 34.66907442
72:   MUT_CTL       f12     72        89    33740 379.10112360    258 407.9149601 43.23889929
73:    WT_CTL        g1     73        89     1957  21.98876404      0 150.4140871 15.94386135
74:     MUT10        g2     74        89     1883  21.15730337      0 112.9026027 11.96765195
75:      MUT9        g3     75        89        9   0.10112360      0   0.7693702  0.08155308
76:      MUT8        g4     76        89        0   0.00000000      0   0.0000000  0.00000000
77:      MUT7        g5     77        89        0   0.00000000      0   0.0000000  0.00000000
78:      MUT6        g6     78        89    14625 164.32584270      0 367.9194198 38.99938050
79:      MUT5        g7     79        89    10308 115.82022472      0 282.0390673 29.89608134
80:      MUT4        g8     80        89     3891  43.71910112      0 235.0162948 24.91167743
81:      MUT3        g9     81        89    14606 164.11235955      3 408.9459132 43.34818011
82:      MUT2       g10     82        89    20714 232.74157303    118 317.0294125 33.60505051
83:      MUT1       g11     83        89    35864 402.96629213    236 489.6790797 51.90587864
84:   MUT_CTL       g12     84        89    30346 340.96629213    218 414.3528209 43.92131118
85:    WT_CTL        h1     85        89     5688  63.91011236      0 286.1771797 30.33472038
86:     MUT10        h2     86        89        1   0.01123596      0   0.1059998  0.01123596
87:      MUT9        h3     87        89        0   0.00000000      0   0.0000000  0.00000000
88:      MUT8        h4     88        89      536   6.02247191      0  53.8480559  5.70788251
89:      MUT7        h5     89        89     1071  12.03370787      0 113.5257729 12.03370787
90:      MUT6        h6     90        89     9495 106.68539326      0 367.4626015 38.95095786
91:      MUT5        h7     91        89       10   0.11235955      0   0.6980200  0.07398997
92:      MUT4        h8     92        89        0   0.00000000      0   0.0000000  0.00000000
93:      MUT3        h9     93        89    19009 213.58426966      0 395.8312258 41.95802602
94:      MUT2       h10     94        89    41792 469.57303371    303 487.6894477 51.69497807
95:      MUT1       h11     95        89    38532 432.94382022    387 383.2050353 40.61965250
96:   MUT_CTL       h12     96        89    23303 261.83146067    135 332.8016825 35.27690780
    condition loc_coord loc_id n_samples sum_dark         mean median          sd         sem
```

And this is the code that I am trying to use to generate this plot:

```
#plot the mean of the phase over time, colored by condition
p_mean_condition_time <- ggplot((sum_tab_cond_Loc), aes(x=condition, y=mean, color=condition, fill=condition, group=condition)) +
  geom_line(lwd=1) + 
  geom_point(size=5,shape=22, stroke=1.4, color="black") +
  labs(title=" ", x='Conditions', y = "Means of Pixel Differences") + 
  theme_classic(base_size = 20)+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sem, ymax=mean+sem), width=0.1, position=position_dodge(width=0.9))
```

[image]

It works except for one thing, which I have not found a solution to yet:
The x-axis ticks are out of order because they are alphabetized once the graph is made. I've found some resources online that talk about reordering, but I'm not sure how to handle this case since I have both letters and numbers in my category labels. Is there a way of doing this that doesn't require explicitly declaring the order of the variables? Or does ggplot only allow alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the variable is a factor with the levels in the order you want.  `gtools::mixedsort()` (and `mixedorder` from the same package) are useful for this. Probably

```r
sum_tab_cond_time$condition <- factor(sum_tab_cond_time$condition,
              levels = gtools::mixedsort(unique(sum_tab_cond_time$condition)))
```

will do the trick (or the equivalent transformation using `transform()` or `dplyr::mutate()`)

Comment: Thanks, Ben! It doesn't seem to change the figures that are generated, though. Do you happen to have other ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, I realized I made a mistake in my implementation and this worked! Thank you!